# Merge titles as searchable content when closing-as-dupe and merging dupes

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, canonical, merged-questions

One more idea to get us to **the canonical post** for duplicates to refer to.

When an unanswered posts is marked as a duplicate (more now will be unanswered thanks to the dupehammer), then its title is appended onto the duped question as ancillary content.  Then when searching is done the terms of that title will be searched also, thereby eliminating the need to keep those dupes around.

For answered posts, there would need to be merging, but the same mechanic could apply to the title.  I'd even have a checkbox in the closing/merging process for the moderators/dupehammers involved to check if none of the answers are substantial, so that the question is then treated as unanswered for this purpose.

I would think that you wouldn't want all this displayed with the post automatically, but that there would be a button for a popup or a dropdown to list all the ancillary titles for a specific question.

After the merging is done, then the duplicate can now be deleted since it isn't needed for searching or content.

Comment: The problem with just deleting a duplicate is that you'll break existing links to it from other sites, unless you redirect. Another issue is that sometimes a duplicate is re-opened and closed as a duplicate of a better canonical question. Finally, we don't want to have really long titles, they don't look good in Google search results.

Comment: @Cupcake, I'm really referring to "new" duplicates, not old ones that might have links to them, though that would have to be taken into consideration.  I definitely do not mean to have the titles append to each other, the merged titles would be meta-data on the canonical post.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't just the title that's important. It could be the entire question body.

- The duplicate's title might not really make sense with the original's body.
- The duplicate's body might contain specific search terms not present in the title or the original (so deleting the duplicate's body would negatively affect searchability).
- Even if we allow swapping of the body as well - some answers may refer to specific aspects of the original question / its title not present in the duplicate.
- Do we really want hundreds of extraordinarily similar variations on the same title for popular canonical questions?

Oh, and:

- Having many question titles or bodies on the same page will likely cause each of those to not be weighted particularly highly, so Stack Overflow could suffer in terms of search ranking.

How about an auto-redirect from the duplicate, with a message at the top? Something like:

> You have been redirected here from [a duplicate](http://a_no-redirect_question_link.example.com). Flag or vote to reopen the duplicate if you believe this isn't a duplicate. [Expand the question V](http://blah_blah_read_tool-tip_blah_blah.example.com).

Is this possible? Can we have questions which <strike>Google</strike> search engines will see as normal pages but will actually just redirect everyone who gets there? (unless they following the above non-redirecting link)

---

Something that *should* be possible (if the above isn't) is to have the pages for each of these redirect links exist (so "You have been redirected here" isn't just a message, but in fact fundamentally part of the page - we have a separate page for the original question for each duplicate), where we could have the duplicate's title and body be predominantly presented to the search engine (i.e. the title as the page title and the body before the original's body).

Comment: You have some good points, but I was mostly focused on SE's search engine.  I don't know enough about SEO and the parameters of Google's indexing to know if there are practical limits.  I just know we desperately need a canonical methodology to curb the dupe problem.

Comment: My 2nd point (which is perhaps the most important) also applies to SE search.

Comment: And what I don't know is when bodies are searched in addition to titles.

Comment: I believe bodies are always searched, unless you use `"title:"` (but I assume results in titles are classified as more relevant).